# joomla профайлинг узнать что тормозит сайт

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3

Есть Сайт на котором установлена куча плагинов, и все за что то отвечают (нужные). пробовал отключить все - ошибка сайт не работает. вобщем копаться и изучать каждый времени уйдет куча.

у меня такой вопрос, есть ли у джомлы какой то дебаг? Чтобы посмотреть какие запросы отрабатываются, какие файлы подключаются, сколько времени отрабатывает каждый плагин, цель узнать узкое место, скрипт, а его уже отключить или исправить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, конечно есть инструмент. Для включения необходимо перейти в админке **SYSTEM** - **Global Configuration** - **Systems** (см. скрин):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее включаете **Debug System** После включения, в нижней части сайта заметите табы в которых инфа сколько ресурсов было затрачено и куда...(База, Сессии и т.д)

Ещё один совет, можете так же проверить что тормозит в консоле браузера **F12** вкладка **Network**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо) как я сразу не заметил